# Best way to find element with the same signature in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I've been asked this question on a interview. What is the best way to find particular button on a page, from two identical buttons?

Two buttons like this on a page, i need to find the second.

**button class="button-signin" name="btnlogin_login" value="Login" type="submit"> Sign In /button>**

I've answered that I'd locate both and choose what I need from the list - they said that it's no good, because page can be changed. Can you suggest me the good way to do this?

Comment: you can locate based on index

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the buttons must be child elements of some HTML elements. 
**Case 1: Parent are different**, you can refer to each button by specify different parent e.g. `cssSelector("#component1 > button")` and `cssSelector("#component2 > button")`.
**Case 2: They have the same parent or path are identical**, there are a couple options.

1. Use index such as XPath `//button[2]` or CssSelector `button:nth-child(2)`
2. Change the application, add something to differentiate the buttons

For case 2, I do think there is no point to have the 2 buttons which have the exactly same properties in the application. Personally, I prefer the option#2

Comment: *Change the application* is the worst answer you can give.

Comment: @Guy It depends on situations. My job is QA and the goal is to guarantee quality of the products. When the application contains something that doesn't make sense, I can raise this and ask developer to fix. In this case, duplicated button may have different functionalities, but why they are the same? This might lead to bug and error in application. Another point is complexity of test cases. Test cases should be simple.

Comment: @Guy can you suggest your answer?

Comment: @Buaban what do you mean of using index? Is it Id? but if it's not available?

Comment: @Buaban And what if the developers used generic templates to build the application and all the buttons have the same signature? you really expect them to change all the buttons?

Comment: @user1274184 This question is quiet broad, I don't want to give answer without more information.

Comment: @Guy I don't want to give answer without more information

Is that what you would answered on a interview? :)

Comment: @user1274184 Ofcourse not, but I will try to get more information, like the html structure to see if the first suggestion of this answer can apply.

Comment: @user1274184 There are 2 ways to use index. 1. Find them all then get the second element. 2. Use locator such as XPath `//button[2]` or CssSelector `button:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If they said to find always the second element I would go for a solution like this:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.class("button-signin"));
if(buttons.size() > 1){
    buttons.get(1);
}
```

But what dont make sense for me is what they told you, than the page can change...Technically if the page change you should modify yours tests to make them easier to find elements save time and make them more readable, you cant do a test forever as a page is not forever.

Comment: I actually inswered like this - find both and use second. I don't know why they said it isn't good :( maybe there is a better option...

Comment: The best approach is a compromise between readable and find elements easily, because you will improve your performance, is not efficient if you does getElements("div").get(54) because you now is the number 54 in your page, I think the solution i give you should be good enough i dont understand the reasons to say was not valid